# Facing an issue with switching screens in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm not really familiar with the usage of screenmanager class due to which i'm not able to switch to the screen with the name "Title 4" although i'm setting the current screen to "Title 4".The current screen remains the same for some strange reason("Title 2").I'm trying to switch screens using the method ok_button_hit() present in the AnotherScreen(Screen) class.Can someone point out the mistake i'm making here?

ABC.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton

check_id=0
menu=''
class FoodListButton(ListItemButton):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    username_input = ObjectProperty()
    passwd_input = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.boxp = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.labs = Label(text='')
        self.boxp.add_widget(self.labs)

        self.box = BoxLayout()
        self.box.orientation = 'horizontal'
        btn5 = Button(text="ok", size_hint=(0.5, 0.5))
        btn5.bind(on_release=self.success)
        self.box.add_widget(btn5)
        self.box.add_widget(Button(text='cancel', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), on_release=self.cancel_button_hit))
        self.boxp.add_widget(self.box)
        self.popup1 = Popup(title="LOGIN SUCCESSFUL",
                            content=self.boxp,
                            size=(200, 200),
                            size_hint=(0.3, 0.3),
                            auto_dismiss=True)

    def checkin(self):
        if self.username_input.text == "root" and self.passwd_input.text == "root":
            self.labs.text = self.username_input.text
            self.popup1.open()
        else:
            self.popup1.title = 'Failed Login'
            self.labs.text = 'Failed'
            self.popup1.open()

    def cancel_button_hit(self, instance):
        self.popup1.dismiss()

    def success(self, instance):
        self.popup1.dismiss()
        self.manager.current = 'Title 2'


class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AnotherScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.boxp = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.labs = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.boxp.add_widget(self.labs)

        self.box = BoxLayout()
        self.box.orientation = 'horizontal'
        btn5 = Button(text="OK", size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), on_release=self.ok_button_hit)

        self.box.add_widget(btn5)
        self.box.add_widget(Button(text='cancel', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), on_release=self.cancel_button_hit))
        self.boxp.add_widget(self.box)
        self.popup1 = Popup(title="Enter Customer ID",
                            content=self.boxp,
                            size=(400, 400),
                            size_hint=(0.3, 0.3),
                            auto_dismiss=False)
        self.popup2 = Popup(title="Failed",
                            content=Label(text='''You don't seem to have a customer id. 
                                          Please check in first'''),
                            size=(400, 400),
                            size_hint=(0.3, 0.3),
                            auto_dismiss=True)

    def check_cust_id(self):
        self.custid = self.labs.text
        #check with database
        if True:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def cancel_button_hit(self, instance):
        self.popup1.dismiss()

    def ok_button_hit(self, instance):
        if self.check_cust_id():
            self.popup1.dismiss()
            global menu
            k='Title'+menu
            print(k)
            self.manager.current = k
        else:
            self.popup1.dismiss()
            self.popup2.open()
            self.popup1.dismiss()


    def res_clicked(self):

        global menu
        menu = ' 4'
        self.popup1.open()

    def lan_clicked(self):
        self.popup1.open()
        global menu
        menu = ' 5'

    def game_clicked(self):
        self.popup1.open()
        global menu
        menu += ' 6'

    def checkout_clicked(self):
        self.popup1.open()
        global menu
        menu += ' 7'
    def check_in(self):
        self.manager.current = 'Title 3'


class Res_Page(Screen):
    total_food_bill = 0
    food_input = ObjectProperty()
    food_list = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Res_Page, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.boxp = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.labs = Label(text=" ")
        self.boxp.add_widget(self.labs)

        self.box = BoxLayout()
        self.box.orientation = 'horizontal'
        btn5 = Button(text="OK", size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), on_release=self.ok_button_hit)

        self.box.add_widget(btn5)
        self.popup1 = Popup(title="Food Bill",
                            content=self.boxp,
                            size=(200, 200),
                            size_hint=(0.3, 0.3),
                            auto_dismiss=False)
        self.popup2 = Popup(title="Error",
                            content=Label(text='''Sorry we don't make that'''),
                            size=(200, 200),
                            size_hint=(0.3, 0.3),
                            auto_dismiss=True)

    def ok_button_hit(self, instance):
        self.popup1.dismiss()
        self.manager.current = 'Title 2'

    def submit_food(self):
        food_name = self.food_input.text
        # Check if food is present
        if (True):
            self.food_list.adapter.data.extend([food_name])
            self.food_list._trigger_reset_populate()
            # Retreive price and subtract from total amount
        else:
            self.popup2.open()

    def delete_food(self, *args):

        if self.food_list.adapter.selection:
            selection = self.food_list.adapter.selection[0].text
            # Check if food is present
            if (True):
                self.food_list.adapter.data.remove(selection)
                self.student_list._trigger_reset_populate()
                # Retreive price and subtract from total amount
            else:
                self.popup2.open()

    def bill_food(self):
        self.labs.text = str(self.total_food_bill)
        self.popup1.open()


class checkinscrn(Screen):
    def checkin_nextscr(self):
        self.manager.current = 'Title 4'


class checkinadv(Screen):
   pass




class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('ABC.kv')
        my_screenmanager = ScreenManager()
        screen1 = LoginScreen(name='Title 1')
        screen2 = AnotherScreen(name='Title 2')
        screen3 = checkinscrn(name='Title 3')
        screen4 = AnotherScreen(name='Title 4')
        screen14 = checkinadv(name='Title 14')

        my_screenmanager.add_widget(screen1)
        my_screenmanager.add_widget(screen2)
        my_screenmanager.add_widget(screen3)
        my_screenmanager.add_widget(screen4)
        #my_screenmanager.add_widget(screen14)
        return my_screenmanager


MainApp().run()
```

ABC.kv file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
<ScreenManagement>:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    LoginScreen:
    AnotherScreen:
    Res_Page:
    checkinscrn:
    checkinadv:


<LoginScreen>:
    name: 'Title 1'
    orientation: "vertical"
    username_input: username
    passwd_input: passwd

    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    BoxLayout:
        padding:[10,50]
        spacing: 40
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Username"
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [200, 50]
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'left_x': 1, 'center_y': 0.5}


        TextInput:
            id: username
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [400, 75]
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}


        Label:
            text: "Password"
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [200, 50]
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'left_x': 0, 'center_y': 0.5}

        TextInput:
            id: passwd
            password: True
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [400, 75]
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

        Button:
            on_release: root.checkin()
            text: 'Login'
            font_size: 50
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [400, 75]
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}


<AnotherScreen>:
    name: 'Title 2'
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    BoxLayout:
        padding:[10,50]
        spacing: 40
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            on_release: root.check_in()
            text: 'Check In'
            font_size: 50
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [400, 45]
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}


        Button:
            on_release: root.res_clicked()
            text: 'Restaurant'
            font_size: 50
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [400, 45]
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}


        Button:
            on_release: root.lan_clicked()
            text: 'Laundry'
            font_size: 50
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [400, 45]
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

        Button:
            on_release: root.game_clicked()
            text: 'Gaming'
            font_size: 50
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [400, 45]
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

        Button:
            on_release: root.checkout_clicked()
            text: 'Check Out'
            font_size: 50
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [400, 45]
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}


        Button:
            on_release: app.root.current = 'Title 1'
            text: 'Log Out'
            font_size: 50
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [400, 45]
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}


<Res_Page>:
    name: 'Title 4'
    orientation: "vertical"
    food_input: food_name
    food_list: food_list_view
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "40dp"

        Label:
            text: "Dish"
        TextInput:
            id: food_name


    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "40dp"
        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            size_hint_x: 15
            on_press: root.submit_food()
        Button:
            text: "Delete"
            size_hint_x: 15
            on_press: root.delete_food()
        Button:
            text: "Generate Bill"
            size_hint_x: 15
            on_press: root.bill_food()

    ListView:
        id: students_list_view
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data=[], cls=main.FoodListButton)






<checkinscrn>:
    name: 'Title 3'
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    name_input: name
    address_input: addr
    checkin_input: cin
    checkout_input: cout
    BoxLayout:
        padding:[10,50]
        spacing: 40
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: 'ENTER NAME'
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [50, 25]
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

        TextInput:
            id: name
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [50, 25]
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

        Label:
            text: 'ENTER ADDRESS'
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [50, 25]
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

        TextInput:
            id: addr
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [50, 25]
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        Label:
            text: 'ENTER CHECK IN DATE'
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [50, 25]
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

        TextInput:
            id: cin
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [50, 25]
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

        Label:
            text: 'ENTER CHECK OUT DATE'
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [50, 25]
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

        TextInput:
            id: cout
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [50, 25]
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

        Button:
            on_release: root.checkin_nextscr()
            text: 'CHECK IN'
            font_size: 50
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [50, 25]
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

<checkinadv>:
    name: 'Title 14'
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    BoxLayout:
        padding:[10,50]
        spacing: 40
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: 'your check in id is'
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            size_hint_y: 0
            size: [50, 25]
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
```

Comment: Seems to work for me. Please describe the exact steps you take in running the app and what goes wrong.

Comment: The application is basically a hotel management system where the user has to login first to enter the main menu screen.The problem is with the restaurant button in the main menu. When it is clicked the current screen is supposed to be replaced by the restaurant screen (title 4 in this case) but that doesn't seem to be happening, the current screen remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MainApp.build()` method, you create a screen named `Title 4`, but you are creating another `AnotherScreen`, not a `Res_Page`. So switching to `Title 4` is switching to another `AnotherScreen`